# User choose where to save file when exporting from ASP.net to Excel using VBA

Tags: asp.net, vba, excel

I have a function that writes from ASP.net to EXCEL using worksheet VBA coding, where I export the datatable and modify every Excel cell the way I want to.

But I have a problem : On Export, i want to ask the user if he wants to Open or Save the file

I wrote this code, the Open / Save As pop-up didn't work :

(I found code that exports the data table to excel without design but I want my report to be better organized)

```
 Sub WriteToExcel(ByVal DATE1 As String, ByVal DATE2 As String)
        Dim oExcel As Object
        Dim oBook As Object
        Dim oSheet As Object
        Dim DT As New DataTable
        Dim filename As String = "Report-" & Date.Now.ToShortDateString.Replace("/", "-") & " " & Date.Now.ToShortTimeString.Replace(":", "-") & ".xls"


        Try


            DT = Session("datatable")

            If DT.Rows.Count > 0 Then


                oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

                oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

                oSheet.Range("D1").Value = "Service Based Daily/Monthly Revenu"
                oSheet.Range("D1").Font.Bold = True
                oSheet.Range("D1").font.size = 13
                oSheet.Range("D2").Value = "From " & DATE1 & " to " & DATE2
                oSheet.Range("D2").Font.Bold = True
                oSheet.Range("D2").font.size = 13
                oSheet.Range("D1:E1:F1").MergeCells = True
                oSheet.Range("D2:E2:F2").MergeCells = True

                oSheet.Range("B4").Value = "Report Build Time: " & Date.Now.ToShortDateString & " " & Date.Now.ToShortTimeString
                oSheet.Range("B4").Font.Bold = False
                oSheet.Range("B4").font.size = 11
                oSheet.Range("B4:C4:D4:E4").Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 172)
                oSheet.Range("B4:C4:D4:E4").MergeCells = True


                oSheet.Range("B6").Value = "Service Name"
                oSheet.Range("C6").Value = "Hits"
                oSheet.Range("D6").Value = "Revenue"
                oSheet.Range("E6").Value = "Service Cost"



                With oSheet.Range("B6:C6:D6:E6")
                    .Font.Bold = True
                    .font.size = 13
                    .font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    .Interior.Color = RGB(70, 134, 196)
                    .HorizontalAlignment = -4108
                    .VerticalAlignment = -4108
                    .WrapText = False
                    .Orientation = 0
                    .AddIndent = False
                    .IndentLevel = 0
                    .ShrinkToFit = False
                    .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 20
                    .MergeCells = False
                End With


                Dim i As Integer = 7

                For Each dRow As DataRow In DT.Rows

                    oSheet.Range("B" & i).Value = dRow("Service_Name").ToString()
                    oSheet.Range("C" & i).Value = dRow("Hits").ToString()
                    oSheet.Range("D" & i).Value = dRow("Revenue").ToString()
                    oSheet.Range("E" & i).Value = dRow("Service_Cost").ToString()


                    oSheet.Range("B" & i & ":C" & i & ":D" & i & ":E" & i).HorizontalAlignment = -4108
                    oSheet.Range("B" & i & ":C" & i & ":D" & i & ":E" & i).VerticalAlignment = -4108

                    i += 1


                Next

                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" & filename)
                Response.BinaryWrite(oExcel)


                oBook = Nothing
                oExcel.Quit()
                oExcel = Nothing
                GC.Collect()
            End If


    End Sub
```

I want to change this part :

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" & filename)
Response.BinaryWrite(oExcel)
```

**I want the user to choose where he wants to save the file.** Any suggestion?

Comment: Response just sends the file to a browser. Then, depending on browser and its settings user can either save or open it. I doubt that you can control this.

Comment: @taosique This is saving the whole page design, and not the excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to force the save as dialogue by using attachment rather than inline.

```
Response.Clear
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & filename)
```

Comment: I tried this. The pop-up shows but the "Open" option is showing my whole html page in excel instead of the oExcel object only...

Comment: Try Response.Clear before writing to the page.